# How to get the SHA-1 key in Android Studio for debug mode?

Tags: keytool

I am a part time student to learn Android studio.
I have to create a new project with lecturer's sample and try to get the **SHA-1 key** for connect the database with firebase.
when I use **key tool** at **command prompt**, there is no any response at screen.
I tried to search you-tube / this forum, they taught me to use **Gradle Bar** and click **.app** and **.android**.
but I tried the same moves, but there is no android folder under .app and .task folder.

I was able to do it successfully in classroom but not at home.

How should I get the SHA-1 key ? Am I need to update the project or import any other class ? how should I do ?

How should I get the SHA-1 key ? I used keytool but no response and gradle but no "android" folder.

Am I need to update the project or import any other class ? how should I do ?